# What physical conditions should be present on a planet for humanoid bird-creatures to exist?

Tags: science-based, planets, physics, atmosphere, avian

I'm writing a fantasy novel with a sentient human-bird species. These creatures magically transform, growing feathers etc. becoming essentially giant birds.
What would the general conditions on this planet be like to be able to host such enormous birds?
Just to note, their flight has nothing to do with magic, so I don't believe that to be particularly relevant.
Specifications:

- Wingspan is roughly 10m
- Weight is roughly 30kg

What I would like to know:

- What would the gravity be like on that planet to be able to support such large birds? (I was thinking maybe slightly less than Earth, but would it need that or not?)
- What would the oxygen levels be like, and would that affect the species' flight (it is theorized that dinosaurs grew so large because of oxygen levels)

Any other points and corrections would be welcome.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This question is a good fit for the site.

Comment: You should probably have the magic tag because of the magical transformation.

Comment: Since a lot of the conditions would vary depending on the value of others, please give us at least a few of the basics among: surface gravity, atmospheric pressure, atmos density, atmos composition, similarity of muscle composition to terrestrial birds, whether they need to take-off from the ground - or can climb and then glide when needed. (That's for the [tag:science-based] tag, the magic tag would leave it open to wider interpretation). More info would be appreciated to 'give us a start' as it were.

Comment: Pterosaurs grew to nearly that size and weighed significantly more, so "Earth around the time of pterosaurs" is your answer.

Comment: I'd say we'll need a bitd more information on your bird people (how large are them? What method of flight do they use? What are their wings like? What aerial feats must they be capable of performing? Do they fly often and for long periods of time?) Also since birds need more muscular legs than pterosaurs and the pterosaurs with such a wingspan are expected to have weighted around 250 kg, those bird people seem a bit too light (especially since pelagornis, the largest flying bird ever, weighted between 22 and 40 kg and had a wingspan between 6.1 and 7.4 meters).

Answer (score 2):

I would look into the evolution of animals native to New Zealand.   One of the interesting things about New Zealand is that it has 4 known species of native mammals, of which three are bats and one is a mouse sized land mammal.   Of those four, two (one bat and the unique mammal) are now extinct.   It wasn't until human migration that mammals of any kind gained a foothold on the island.

One such issue large birds have is that all birds lay eggs with fragile shells that easily break.   Most species of birds are small enough that they can build a nest on high spaces that are difficult for predators to climb... but large birds cannot and must lay them in nests on the ground, where they are vulnerable to most foraging animals that will see them as a snack... or even large animals that will simply crush the eggs underfoot.   Reptile eggs avoid this issue by having tougher leathery shells AND by burying the eggs under the ground to add another difficulty in finding the clutch (the burying isn't just for safety... reptiles gender is determined by egg temperature and a slight variation can mean the difference between a male and female hatchling.  Since most reptiles will abandon the clutch after laying the eggs, this is the only way to ensure they are kept warm.).

Answer (score 2):

The largest flying bird on Earth right now is the wandering albatross, which can reach a wingspan of up to 3.5 m and weights up to 12.5 kg. I know these things don't scale linearly but this should serve to demonstrate an infant of your bird species could probably fly on Earth.

Then we get to the era of dinosaurs. Yes, there was more oxygen back then, but then again we have birds such as the condor that can fly at very high altitudes where oxygen is scarce. That probably shouldn't be an issue.

The largest flying lizard was the giraffe-sized [Quetzalcoatlus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quetzalcoatlus), with a wingspan of up to 10m and an estimated weight as an adult up to 250 kg! Your birds, with the same wingspan but being 8x lighter, should have no trouble flying here on Earth at all.

So as long as your planet is similar to Earth, your bird creatures should feel comfortable flying in it.

Answer (score 1):

Low gravity would probably help, but not to low that you lose  Atmospheric pressure (yes more oxygen would be preferable) . A planet with lots of powerful air currents would also be a nice touch. The hybrid could use them similarly to how we use sea curents.